# Save vim settings

Tags: vim

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcsmu.png)

I spent a bit of time getting my vim the way it looks like in the attached picture. My question, is there a way to get this settings as default when I open my vim? A explorer at the upper left corner, a terminal at the bottom left corner, and the editor at the right. Should I edit anything such as the .vimrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `:mksession ~/.vim/session.vim` to save the current session in a vimscript file.
If you get this error message:

```
E189: "~/.vim/session.vim" exists (add ! to override)
```

Append a bang to `:mksession`:

```
:mksession! ~/.vim/session.vim
          ^
```

You can control what Vim will write in it with the `'sessionoptions'` option.
The latter is a comma separated list of items.

FWIW, here is how I set the option:

```
set sessionoptions=help,tabpages,winsize
```

In particular, I don't include the items `options` and `localoptions`, because when I source back a session, I want to start with sane option values/mappings, no matter what experiments I was performing when running `:mksession`.
For the same reason, I only include the minimum of items I need (i.e. `help`, `tabpages`, `winsize`); you may need more or less.

---

Now that you have a session file, you can close everything with:

```
:sil! tabonly | sil! only | enew
      │              │      │
      │              │      └ load a new unnamed buffer
      │              └ close all windows except the current one
      └ close all tab pages except the current one
```

And you can get your session back by running:

```
:so ~/.vim/session.vim
```

---

When starting Vim from the shell, you can get your session back with the `-S` argument:

```
$ vim -S ~/.vim/session.vim
      ^^
```

---

You can automate the sourcing of the session file like this:

```
augroup my_session
    au!
    au VimEnter * ++nested call s:load_session_on_vimenter()
augroup END

fu s:load_session_on_vimenter() abort
    let file = $HOME.'/.vim/session.vim'
    if filereadable(file)
    \ && ! argc()
    \ && &errorfile is# 'errors.err'
        so ~/.vim/session.vim
    endif
endfu
```

---

For more information, see:

```
:h 'ssop
:h :mksession
:h :so
:h -S
```